# How to get a piece of text from PHP file

Tags: php

From wp-config.php file I need to get DB name, username, password values without including the wp-config file and assign them to three separate variable for further use.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');
define('DB_USER', 'someuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'somepass');
```

my script will be in the same folder. No I don't want to use any WordPress functions.

Comment: So, read the file and manually parse it. Though that's a lot of wasted work when the obvious way to do it is just to include it. Btw, if you do include it there's no reason to assign the values you need to separate variables...

Comment: I would also recommend to follow JimL's advice. What is the reason you don't want to include it?

Comment: You could read it in with `file()` to get an array of lines. Then loop through it and do some regex-extraction stuff. A lot of hassle. If there's nothing keeping you from just incuding it and letting `define()` do its job, I'd rather do it that way.

Comment: including it is redirecting the page to WordPress install screen if WordPress is not yet setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** don't want to include the file, as mentioned in the comments already,
we can read the file contents into an array with `file()`.

The iterate over each line and apply some cleanup, until we get to a format we can work with:

```
<?php

$config = file('wp-config.php');

$dbLines = [];

foreach($config as $line){
    if (stristr($line,"define('DB_")!==FALSE){
        $dbLines[] = $line;
    }
}

array_walk($dbLines, 'cleanup'); 
// apply the cleanup() function to all members of the array, basically to each line

function cleanup(&$value){
    // replace the leading 'define(' and trailing closing bracket
    $value = str_replace(
        array("define(",");"),'',$value
        );
    $value = preg_replace('#\s+//(.*)#','',$value); // remove the comments
}

// at this point we have a csv structure with a single quote as the delimiter
// comma+space as a separator

$dbConfig = [];

foreach ($dbLines as $dbline){
    // read the line into separate variables and build an array
    list($key,$value) = (str_getcsv($dbline,', ',"'"));
    $dbConfig[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($dbConfig);
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [DB_NAME] => putyourdbnamehere
    [DB_USER] => usernamehere
    [DB_PASSWORD] => yourpasswordhere
    [DB_HOST] => localhost
    [DB_CHARSET] => utf8
    [DB_COLLATE] =>
)
```

If you want to access a single element from the array, just

```
print $dbConfig['DB_HOST'];
```

Comment: It was working fine for me, I will look into that. You are welcome!